# How to create a dataframe from a python groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My first dataframe contains a column consisting of a unique ID of a card (card_id):

```
treino.head(5)

            card_id   feature_1   feature_2   feature_3
0   C_ID_92a2005557           5         2             1
1   C_ID_3d0044924f           4         1             0
2   C_ID_d639edf6cd           2         2             0
3   C_ID_186d6a6901           4         3             0
4   C_ID_cdbd2c0db2           1         3             0
```

my second dataframe is the history of where these cards were passed:

```
df2.head(5)

   authorized_flag          card_id  city_id category_1      merchant_id
0                Y  C_ID_92a2005557       88          N  M_ID_e020e9b302
1                Y  C_ID_d639edf6cd       88          N  M_ID_86ec983688
2                Y  C_ID_92a2005557       88          N  M_ID_979ed661fc
3                Y  C_ID_92a2005557       88          N  M_ID_e6d5ae8ea6
4                Y  C_ID_92a2005557       88          N  M_ID_e020e9b302
5                Y  C_ID_4e6213e9bc      333          N  M_ID_50af771f8d
6                Y  C_ID_92a2005557       88          N  M_ID_5e8220e564
7                Y  C_ID_4e6213e9bc        3          N  M_ID_9d41786a50
8                Y  C_ID_d639edf6cd       88          N  M_ID_979ed661fc
```

when using:

```
merged_left = pd.merge (left = df1, right = df2, how = left, left_on = 'card_id', right_on = 'card_id')
```

it multiplies the lines of card_id because in the second dataframe a card_id appears several times. I already put it to do the join on the left to just leave the card_id uniquely of the first dataframe but my problem continues.

I already understood that it multiplies the lines because df2 is a shopping history and the card_id appear several times but I can not solve it.

already tried something like:

```
df2.groupby (['card_id', 'merchant_id']). size (). reset_index ()
```

but I still have several rows of the same card_id, could they help me to create a dataframe with only 1 line of each unique card_id and merchant_id, will I have to create a new variable with their data summarized?

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly, but would `merged_left.drop_duplicates(['card_id'], keep='last')` work?

Comment: did this work, would it keep the merchant_id where the card_id most appeared in df2?

Answer (score 0):

If you want just a list of *card_id* / *merchant_id* (which user has bought
something from which merchant), it is enough to draw data from *df2*:

```
df2[['card_id', 'merchant_id']].drop_duplicates()
```

As you can see, no *groupby* is needed, just read the columns in question and
drop duplicates.

A little more complex case is when you want e.g. how many times particular
*card_id* has bought something from particular *merchant_id*.
Then *groupby* is needed and the value wanted you will get using *size()* function:

```
df2.groupby(['card_id', 'merchant_id']).size()
```

possibly completed with *.reset_index()* as you did.

Of course, particular *card_id* occurs in several output row, but each time
with **different** *merchant_id* (and relevant number of transactions
between these 2 subjects).

So make up your mind what information you want besides *card_id* and *merchant_id*.
This is necessary to decide what code is needed to generate the answer.